# Compile Jnetpcap library for ARM platform?

Tags: linux, arm, pcap

I am trying to execute a java project on arm platform. my code use jnetpcap library. but when i execute the program it shows me an error

"/usr/lib/jnetpcap.so: cannot open shared object: no such file or directory (possible cause: can't load IA 32-bit .so on a ARM-bit platform"

so what i can understand is that i need to get the library compiled for arm platform? does this library exist? how can i get it ?

thx for you a lot

Answer (score 1):

So I've done the Job.

this is the link to the library jnetpcap compiled for Arm Architecture :

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48596044/JnetPcap_For_Arm/libJnetPcap_Arm_Architecture.jar

install : dpkg jnetpcap_*.deb

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  You are trying to use an x86 library on an ARM platform.  What you will need to do is get the source code for jNetPCap and compile it on the ARM platform, unless someone else has done it already.  Once you have that, publish that lib in your ARM server and try running your code once more.

[Someone in stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952878/android-ndk-trying-to-port-jnetpcap) has a posting on porting this on ARM, perhaps this will give you some guidance.

Hope this helps!